# Reimport exported file and make all the cuts same

Tags: premiere

In Premiere I am working on an hour long project with around 500 cuts from 3 cameras.

Since there is heavy grading and noise corrections to do, when I get this kind of footage my first export is only color, then I reimport the clip and do all the noise corrections.

This kind of workflow saves several hours on export and I have tried it many times so I do not plan to change it.

Question: Is there a way to make all the cuts on imported clip like they are on timeline ?

Answer (score 0):

It could be done automatically with scripting, but scripting premiere is undocumented and requires a bit of experience.

A workaround is to use the keyboard shortcuts. If you put the reimported clip on a new track in the original timeline you can use the <kbd>↓</kbd> key to jump to the next cut, then hit <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>ctrl/⌘</kbd><kbd>k</kbd> to add an edit at the playhead across all tracks. Rinse, repeat. You could even map the add edit command to a single key to make it easier, e.g. <kbd>x</kbd>. Then its just a matter of hitting <kbd>↓</kbd>then <kbd>x</kbd> 500 hundred times. Something like [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (there's probably an equivalent for those still stuck with a Mac) can automate that process to make it even easier.

Or you could use a less insane workflow. Oops did I say that out loud?

Comment: Unfortunately not, If I export everything at once it takes around 17h, if I split export in doing color on first export and nosie reduction on 2nd export its total of 4h.

Comment: What software are you using for your grade?

Comment: Everything is done in Premiere Pro.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace your edited but ungraded footage with your graded footage, you can do this by using "[Replace Footage](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/premiere-elements/using/replace-footage.html)", to swap the footage out, which will keep your edits but replace the media used.  Make sure all the graded media is exactly the same length and frame rate as your ungraded media.  Make sure you save your project as a different version before doing the Replace operation in case anything goes wrong.

But, I would strongly suggest that your workflow isn't saving you time.

My suggestion:

Do the cuts first before the grading.

If you plan to universally grade each camera, ie one grade per camera, you can do this by applying noise reduction & Lumetri effects to the [Source Clip](https://helpx.adobe.com/uk/premiere-pro/using/master-clip-effects.html) instead of to each individual clip in your timeline.

Your current process requires you to render at least 3 hours of graded footage.

The proposed version only requires rendering 1 hour of graded footage. If you want to see how the footage is looking while you're editing you can turn the noise reduction & Lumetri effects on or off quickly by bypassing the effects on the source footage.